# Identify Hairy Plant with Purple Flowers

Tags: identification

I am always looking for hairy plants because they are photogenic. I saw this online, but there is no information at all.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing the photographer has a big sheet of green material to use as the background. It's a good "dodge" when you can't arrange for a good blurred background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a Pasqueflower, probably the species known botanically as [*Pulsatilla vulgaris*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsatilla_vulgaris). Pasqueflowers are low-growing plants (maybe 10-12 inches tall) that bloom in May in zone 5 (US). They're hardy to US Zone 4 at least and long-lived. They have rather showy feathery seedheads and have blue, white, or red flowers.

There are other even hairier species; for example, ([*Pulsatilla ambiqua*](https://www.shootgardening.co.uk/plant/pulsatilla-ambigua), is the same size as *P. vulgaris* but blooms a couple weeks earlier, and when in bud and just breaking into bloom kind of resembles a hairier version of the plant [Audrey](https://www.syfy.com/sites/syfy/files/styles/1200x1200/public/2017/08/Audrey-II.jpg?itok=VaIJAXS9&timestamp=1502289207) in the film "Little Shop of Horrors". Without the teeth, of course.

**P. vulgaris**
[image: Pulsatilla vulgaris]

**P. ambigua**
[image: Pulsatilla ambigua]

Comment: Thanks. It appears to be a bulb that requires cold to be a perrenial. So, I will have to grow it as an annual where I am (zone 10). I can buy them right now at High Country Gardens online.

Comment: It's not a bulb actually, but a rooted perennial. Note that it will require good drainage during (I assume) the autumn through spring period when you'll have it in the garden or container. If you have a spare refrigerator (small dorm fridges work well) and want to try an experiment, you could keep a plant in a container and put it in the fridge in mid-Spring to try to induce dormancy. You'd need to water it infrequently to keep the soil just moist, not wet.

Comment: They will also slowly self seed if they like the area